# SharePoint Foundation DistributedCache Monitorable Token Cache: Failed to get token from distributed

Tags: 2013, development, administration, distributedcache

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection, currently when users try to add/edit a wiki page sometimes they got the following errors :-
:-

```
Sorry, something went wrong 
An unexpected error has occurred. 
Technical Details 


Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: 58f2bb9c-0c74-c0b7-30fc-03bda75f8954 

Date and Time: 25/09/2014 14:20:52
```

OR

```
Sorry, something went wrong 
An unexpected error has occurred. 
Technical Details 


Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: 5ff2bb9c-8cb4-c0b7-30fc-01998f1c81b7 

Date and Time: 25/09/2014 14:21:21
```

so i checked the logs under 15 folder and i find the following related logs for the above correlation ids :-

> [   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.HandleEventCallback[ReceiverType,PropertiesType](Object
>   callbackData)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPThreadPool.WaitCallbackWrapper(Object
>   state)     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)     at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() 
>   ] 5ef2bb9c-0cdd-c0b7-30fc-02f03abdf05b 09/25/2014 14:21:21.56
>     w3wp.exe (0x0994)                           0x1700  SharePoint Foundation
>     DistributedCache
>     00000   Unexpected  SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper::InitializeDataCacheFactory
>   - No cache hosts are present or running in the farm.  5ef2bb9c-fcdd-c0b7-30fc-02c2bdb31137 09/25/2014 14:21:21.56
>     w3wp.exe (0x0994)                           0x1700  SharePoint Foundation
>     DistributedCache                ah24w   Unexpected  Unexpected Exception
>   in SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper::InitializeDataCacheFactory for
>   usage 'DistributedLogonTokenCache' - Exception
>   'System.InvalidOperationException:
>   SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper::InitializeDataCacheFactory - No
>   cache hosts are present or running in the farm.     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper.InitializeDataCacheFactory()'.   5ef2bb9c-fcdd-c0b7-30fc-02c2bdb31137
>   09/25/2014 14:21:21.56    w3wp.exe (0x0994)
>     0x1700  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache
>     air4g   Monitorable Token Cache: Failed to initialize
>   SPDistributedSecurityTokenCache  Exception:
>   'System.InvalidOperationException:
>   SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper::InitializeDataCacheFactory - No
>   cache hosts are present or running in the farm.     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper.InitializeDataCacheFactory()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCache..ctor(String
>   name, TimeSpan timeToLive, SPDistributedCacheContainerType
>   containerType, Boolean encryptData)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPDistributedSecurityTokenCache..ctor(String
>   name, TimeSpan timeToLive, SPDistributedCacheContainerType
>   containerType, Boolean encrptyData, TimeSpan
>   minimumTokenExpirationWindow)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPDistributedSecurityTokenC... 5ef2bb9c-fcdd-c0b7-30fc-02c2bdb31137
>   09/25/2014 14:21:21.56*   w3wp.exe (0x0994)
>     0x1700  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache
>     air4g   Monitorable ...acheInitializer.Init(Object
>   state)'.  5ef2bb9c-fcdd-c0b7-30fc-02c2bdb31137 09/25/2014 14:21:21.56
>     w3wp.exe (0x0994)                           0x15E0  SharePoint Foundation
>     Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: 0
>   nasq,7 air4a,0 air4b,2 agb9s,60 ak8dj,19 b4ly,0 b4ly,15 cm6y,0 cm6y,0
>   cm6y,3 cm6y,6 cm6y,8 cm6y,36 7fz4,0 7fz4,137 b4ly,18 ak8dj,1 ak8dj,2
>   abnwk,107 ak8dj,2 abnwk,10 ajk3p,50 ak8dj,86 ak8dj,2 ak8dj,70 ak8dj,26
>   abnwk,68 ak8dj,59 abnwk,14 ajk3p,85 ak8dj,26 ak8dj,56 ak8dj,9 b4ly,0
>   b4ly,2 a5yc,32 ak8dj,0 ak8dj,46 ak8dj,11 abnwk,44 ak8dj,12 abnwk,5
>   ajk3p,71 ak8dj    5ff2bb9c-cc5b-c0b7-30fc-0b93a4bb6f95 09/25/2014
>   14:21:21.56   w3wp.exe (0x0994)
>     0x15E0  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring
>     b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request
>   (POST:http://www.test.intra:80/kb/CustomerServiceKB/_layouts/15/CreatePublishingPageDialog.aspx?CancelSource=http://www.test.intra/kb/CustomerServiceKB/Pages/Customer%20Service%20KB.aspx&IsDlg=1)).
>   Execution Time=1256.83599451886   5ff2bb9c-cc5b-c0b7-30fc-0b93a4bb6f95
>   09/25/2014 14:21:21.61    w3wp.exe (0x0994)
>     0x10EC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring
>     b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (EnsureListItemsData).
>   Execution Time=37.6121127126492   5ff2bb9c-cc5b-c0b7-30fc-0b93a4bb6f95
>   09/25/2014 14:21:21.65    w3wp.exe (0x0994)
>     0x10EC  SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication
>     amcbl   Medium      Trusted provider is missing. Provider:
>   '00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000'    5ff2bb9c-cc5b-c0b7-30fc-0b93a4bb6f95
>   09/25/2014 14:21:21.72    w3wp.exe (0x0994)
>     0x10EC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring
>     b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (FireWorkflowStartingEvent).
>   Execution Time=10.6246045237593   5ff2bb9c-cc5b-c0b7-30fc-0b93a4bb6f95
>   09/25/2014 14:21:21.73    w3wp.exe (0x0994)
>     0x160C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring
>     nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request
>   (GET:http://www.test.intra:80/kb/CustomerServiceKB/Pages/2222.aspx?ControlMode=Edit&DisplayMode=Design)).
>   Parent No   09/25/2014 14:21:21.73    w3wp.exe (0x0994)
>     0x160C  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data
>     xmnv    Medium      Name=Request
>   (GET:http://www.test.intra:80/kb/CustomerServiceKB/Pages/2222.aspx?ControlMode=Edit&DisplayMode=Design)   5ff2bb9c-8cb4-c0b7-30fc-01998f1c81b7
>   09/25/2014 14:21:21.73    w3wp.exe (0x0994)
>     0x10EC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring
>     nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (WorkflowTelemetryScope).
>   Parent SPSqlClient    5ff2bb9c-cc5b-c0b7-30fc-0b93a4bb6f95 09/25/2014
>   14:21:21.73   w3wp.exe (0x0994)
>     0x160C  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache
>     air4a   Monitorable Token Cache: Failed to get token from distributed
>   cache for '0).w|s-1-5-21-2423832088-805756336-3312544506-1562'.(This
>   is expected during the process warm up or if data cache Initialization
>   is getting done by some other
>   thread).  5ff2bb9c-8cb4-c0b7-30fc-01998f1c81b7 09/25/2014 14:21:21.73
>     w3wp.exe (0x0994)                           0x160C  SharePoint Foundation
>     DistributedCache                air4b   Monitorable Token Cache:
>   Reverting to local cache to get the token for
>   '0).w|s-1-5-21-2423832088-805756336-3312544506-1562'. 5ff2bb9c-8cb4-c0b7-30fc-01998f1c81b7
>   09/25/2014 14:21:21.73    w3wp.exe (0x0994)
>     0x160C  SharePoint Foundation           Authentication Authorization 
>     agb9s   Medium      Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True,
>   UserIdentityName=0#.w|ad-test\user.text,
>   ClaimsCount=30    5ff2bb9c-8cb4-c0b7-30fc-01998f1c81b7 09/25/2014
>   14:21:21.75   mssearch.exe (0x17A0)
>     0x1B50  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Content Plugin
>     ajqe0   High        CSSFeedersManager statistics Regular Crawl group:
>
> ## items in plugin 0; #items in batches ready to submit: 0; # submitted = 0   09/25/2014 14:21:21.75    mssearch.exe (0x17A0)                       0x1B50  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Content Plugin
>
> af7yz   High        CSSFeedersManager statistics Regular Crawl group: avg
>   submit time (recent) 0 sec; avg poll callbacks time (recent) 0 sec;
>   avg batch count (recent) 27; avg processing time (recent) 14
>   09/25/2014 14:21:21.75    mssearch.exe (0x17A0)
>     0x1B50  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Content Plugin
>     aidlw   High        CSSFeedersManager statistics Regular Crawl group: avg
>   submit time 0 sec; avg poll callbacks time 0 sec; avg batch count 27;
>   avg processing time 17; avg successful submit time 0; avg failed
>   submit time 0; # timeout exceptions 0       09/25/2014 14:21:21.75
>     mssearch.exe (0x17A0)                       0x1B50  SharePoint Server
>   Search        Crawler:Content Plugin          af7x4   High        CSSFeeder
>   statistics: session : 5ea2ddcd-73e7-42ef-b31b-1055130fa855;  # items
>   submitted 0; buffer used 0 %, last callback = 09/25/2014 10:46:19; is
>   connection lost = False     09/25/2014 14:21:21.75    mssearch.exe
>   (0x17A0)                      0x1B50  SharePoint Server Search
>     Crawler:Content Plugin          af7x4   High        CSSFeeder statistics:
>   session : c06e5e6c-97b5-48dc-a7ed-4315e491b8bd;  # items submitted 0;
>   buffer used 0 %, last callback = 09/25/2014 11:06:20; is connection
>   lost = False    09/25/2014 14:21:21.75    mssearch.exe (0x17A0)
>     0x1B50  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Content Plugin
>     af7x4   High        CSSFeeder statistics: session :
>   3c01d781-19c2-409e-8967-81164a26929f;  # items submitted 0; buffer
>   used 0 %, last callback = 09/25/2014 13:06:27; is connection lost =
>   False   09/25/2014 14:21:21.75    mssearch.exe (0x17A0)
>     0x1B50  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Content Plugin
>     af7x4   High        CSSFeeder statistics: session :
>   a7cccdbc-92e7-4a89-9700-d1ec9e7fd719;  # items submitted 0; buffer
>   used 0 %, last callback = 09/25/2014 11:46:22; is connection lost =
>   False   09/25/2014 14:21:21.75    mssearch.exe (0x17A0)
>     0x1B50  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Content Plugin
>     af7x4   High        CSSFeeder statistics: session :
>   8775480f-16b5-4852-ac1d-fc85ef51a35d;  # items submitted 0; buffer
>   used 0 %, last callback = 09/25/2014 12:16:23; is connection lost =
>   False   09/25/2014 14:21:21.75    mssearch.exe (0x17A0)
>     0x1B50  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Content Plugin
>     af7x4   High        CSSFeeder statistics: session :
>   ed15bf33-188d-4cd3-960a-f2b1b78f4470;  # items submitted 0; buffer
>   used 0 %, last callback = 09/25/2014 11:17:10; is connection lost =
>   False   09/25/2014 14:21:21.75    mssearch.exe (0x17A0)
>     0x1B50  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Content Plugin
>     af7x4   High        CSSFeeder statistics: session :
>   4639635d-0d31-438f-90c2-75d48434e47f;  # items submitted 0; buffer
>   used 0 %, last callback = 09/25/2014 11:36:21; is connection lost =
>   False   09/25/2014 14:21:21.75    mssearch.exe (0x17A0)
>     0x1B50  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Content Plugin
>     af7x4   High        CSSFeeder statistics: session :
>   356006d9-5779-4cc5-8751-70974eebf9e2;  # items submitted 0; buffer
>   used 0 %, last callback = 09/25/2014 12:06:22; is connection lost =
>   False   09/25/2014 14:21:21.75    mssearch.exe (0x17A0)
>     0x1B50  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Content Plugin
>     af7x4   High        CSSFeeder statistics: session :
>   a8d3a8c8-7044-4bc9-b9a5-248bf0717730;  # items submitted 0; buffer
>   used 0 %, last callback = 09/25/2014 11:16:11; is connection lost =
>   False   09/25/2014 14:21:21.75    mssearch.exe (0x17A0)
>     0x1B50  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Content Plugin
>     af7x4   High        CSSFeeder statistics: session :
>   10cd2b3f-f010-4a78-9d9f-2662f9f3342f;  # items submitted 0; buffer
>   used 0 %, last callback = 09/25/2014 12:46:24; is connection lost =
>   False   09/25/2014 14:21:21.75    mssearch.exe (0x17A0)
>     0x1B50  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Content Plugin
>     af7x4   High        CSSFeeder statistics: session :
>   a5cd2f89-f589-43c1-8755-ab5a287b2ce5;  # items submitted 0; buffer
>   used 0 %, last callback = 09/25/2014 10:36:22; is connection lost =
>   False   09/25/2014 14:21:21.75    mssearch.exe (0x17A0)
>     0x1B50  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Content Plugin
>     af7x4   High        CSSFeeder statistics: session :
>   fa350cf9-73cb-4e53-ac80-5a223e278788;  # items submitted 0; buffer
>   used 0 %, last callback = 09/25/2014 13:16:25; is connection lost =
>   False   09/25/2014 14:21:21.75    mssearch.exe (0x17A0)
>     0x1B50  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Content Plugin

**EDIT 2**
here is the logs after enabling verbose monitoring for correlation id:-**4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275**

```
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        77a3    Verbose     Starting correlation.   4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://www.tgroup.intra/kb/CustomerServiceKB/Pages/12121212 wweqwe.aspx)  4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Verbose     Entering monitored scope (RequestManagement Processing). Parent Request (GET:http://www.tgroup.intra/kb/CustomerServiceKB/Pages/12121212 wweqwe.aspx)   4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Verbose     Entering monitored scope (SPRequestManagement.GetRoutingTargets). Parent RequestManagement Processing   4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              aaz9x   Verbose     Target pool count based on routing rules: 0 4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              aaz9l   Verbose     Initial routing target count: 1 4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Verbose     Leaving Monitored Scope (SPRequestManagement.GetRoutingTargets). Execution Time=0.217904789575211   4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nass    Verbose     ____Execution Time=0.217904789575211    4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nass    Verbose     ____CPU Cycles=463478   4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              aaz9y   Verbose     Target count before throttling: 1   4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              aaz9z   Verbose     Throttling enabled, finding available targets   4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Verbose     Entering monitored scope (SPRequestManagement.EvaluateThrottlingRules). Parent RequestManagement Processing 4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Verbose     Entering monitored scope (Throttling Evaluation). Parent SPRequestManagement.EvaluateThrottlingRules    4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Verbose     Leaving Monitored Scope (Throttling Evaluation). Execution Time=0.0102666679703705  4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nass    Verbose     ____Execution Time=0.0102666679703705   4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nass    Verbose     ____CPU Cycles=20599    4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              ai6y0   Verbose     Lowest threshold after evaluating rules '2147483647'    4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Verbose     Leaving Monitored Scope (SPRequestManagement.EvaluateThrottlingRules). Execution Time=0.128577794105117 4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nass    Verbose     ____Execution Time=0.128577794105117    4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nass    Verbose     ____CPU Cycles=281366   4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              aaz90   Verbose     Available target count based on throttling rules: 1 4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              aaz9n   Verbose     Unthrottled routing target count: 1 4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Verbose     Leaving Monitored Scope (RequestManagement Processing). Execution Time=0.781454067486231    4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nass    Verbose     ____Execution Time=0.781454067486231    4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nass    Verbose     ____CPU Cycles=1692328  4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              aaz9q   Verbose     Final target for request: TGVSPS01  4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              adc7u   Medium      Mapping URI from 'http://www.tgroup.intra:80/kb/CustomerServiceKB/Pages/12121212%20wweqwe.aspx' to 'http://TGVSPS01/kb/CustomerServiceKB/Pages/12121212%20wweqwe.aspx'  4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              aa0ai   Verbose     Copying incoming headers to outgoing request    4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              agmky   Verbose     Existing correlation ID found '4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275', adding header to outgoing request 4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              aa0ak   Verbose     Attempting to send data with method 'GET' to server 4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Verbose     Entering monitored scope (RequestManagement Request Upload). Parent Request (GET:http://www.tgroup.intra/kb/CustomerServiceKB/Pages/12121212 wweqwe.aspx)   4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              aeboc   Verbose     No data was found on the incoming client request    4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Verbose     Leaving Monitored Scope (RequestManagement Request Upload). Execution Time=0.0303111149601416   4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nass    Verbose     ____Execution Time=0.0303111149601416   4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nass    Verbose     ____CPU Cycles=81559    4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x277C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Verbose     Entering monitored scope (SPRoutingReverseProxy Get Response). Parent Request (GET:http://www.tgroup.intra/kb/CustomerServiceKB/Pages/12121212 wweqwe.aspx) 4217bc9c-5cc5-c0b7-30fc-02d3a61b6275
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x1CC8  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        9gc5    Verbose     Thread change; resetting trace level override to 0; resetting correlation to empty list  
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x1CC8  SharePoint Foundation           General                         6t8b    Verbose     Looking up context  site http://www.tgroup.intra:80/kb/CustomerServiceKB/Pages/12121212%20wweqwe.aspx in the farm SharePoint_Config  
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x1CC8  SharePoint Foundation           General                         6t8d    Verbose     Looking up the additional information about the typical site http://www.tgroup.intra:80/kb/CustomerServiceKB/Pages/12121212%20wweqwe.aspx.   
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x1CC8  SharePoint Foundation           General                         6t8f    Verbose     Site lookup is replacing http://www.tgroup.intra:80/kb/CustomerServiceKB/Pages/12121212%20wweqwe.aspx with the alternate access url http://www.tgroup.intra.     
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x1CC8  SharePoint Foundation           General                         6t8g    Verbose     Looking up typical site http://www.tgroup.intra:80/kb/CustomerServiceKB/Pages/12121212%20wweqwe.aspx in web application SPWebApplication Name=SharePoint - 80.   
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x1CC8  SharePoint Foundation           General                         6t8h    Verbose     Found typical site /kb/CustomerServiceKB (10dd91fc-10aa-4f08-a706-8178c2d0ba73) in web application SPWebApplication Name=SharePoint - 80.    
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x04BC)                       0x1D20  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job Rebalance crawl store partitions for 9004fabc-2086-478e-8581-605309dd8161). Execution Time=112.245969809012  4217bc9c-8cbe-c0b7-30fc-04f1a178544b
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x04BC)                       0x1D20  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nass    Verbose     ____SQL Query Count=4   4217bc9c-8cbe-c0b7-30fc-04f1a178544b
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x04BC)                       0x1D20  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nass    Verbose     ____SPRequest Objects=0 4217bc9c-8cbe-c0b7-30fc-04f1a178544b
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  w3wp.exe (0x12DC)                           0x1CC8  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://www.tgroup.intra:80/kb/CustomerServiceKB/Pages/12121212%20wweqwe.aspx)). Parent No     
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x04BC)                       0x1D20  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nass    Verbose     ____CPU Cycles=125203169    4217bc9c-8cbe-c0b7-30fc-04f1a178544b
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x04BC)                       0x1D20  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nass    Verbose     ____Service Calls=0 4217bc9c-8cbe-c0b7-30fc-04f1a178544b
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x04BC)                       0x1D20  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nass    Verbose     ____Execution Time=112.245969809012 4217bc9c-8cbe-c0b7-30fc-04f1a178544b
09/26/2014 01:06:00.53  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x04BC)                       0x1D20  SharePoint Foundation           Usage Infrastructure            d0hz    Verbose     Starting write tra
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the ULS, no cache hosts are present. So either Distributed Cache is simply stopped on a server, and you'll want to start it via Manage Services on Server, or you don't have one, and you'll want to issue Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance.

You will also want to apply [AppFabric CU5](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2932678) and edit the config file per the KB for [AppFabric CU3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2787717).

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes the distributed cache was stopped so i start it. but now i get a new correlation ids problem "77f6bb9c-0c6a-c0b7-30fc-0c22f8a73581", can you check my edit to the original question . kindly note that this problem only happens if i try to add/edit a wiki page and i update the wiki page name .can you adivce pelase?

Comment: Is that the only information associated with that correlation ID? Because there are no errors in your edit. You may want to turn logging up to Verbose and try again.

Comment: i find things such as "UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContainer(SPFileStreamStore spfs, ILockBytes "

Comment: is this an error or not ? also can this be a Bug in sharepoint which does not allow editing wiki page name !!?

Comment: No, that is not an error.

Comment: so can you please advice what can i do ??,,, as currently if a user edit the wiki page name, then he will get an error , and if other users try to add new pages , they are going to receive the same error, so the whole site will became un-usable. and two things to mention , that the page will get the new name (will be update successfully although the user will get an error !!) and also removing the page which have its name changed will solve the problem (of course temporary )

Comment: can you advice please ? if there is a way to fix this? i spend the whole day without any results..

Comment: also i have noted  when the user get the "Unexpected error" when he tries add/edit a page and he refersh the web browser he will be able to see his modifications without any problem !!! very strange problem..

Comment: Is the ULS log set to verbose before you repeat the error?

Comment: ok i set verbose , and i reproduce the error , can you please check my "Edit 2" section inside my original question for more detials?

Comment: can you adivce on this please?

Comment: currently i have app fabric version 1.1.2106.32 ,, so do i need to upgrade ?

Comment: What is "distributed cache" and where can I find it?